# What abilities allow for focus points to be regenerated in combat?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, focus-pool

I’m trying to get a better sense of how official content values focus regeneration for the purpose of balancing a homebrew class. I’m aware of the [Surging Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1702) feat for the cleric, and I seem to recall the Psychic playtest having some similar mechanics?

What is the complete list of feats, abilities, items, or other ways for a character to regain a Focus Point within an encounter, without spending time on the Refocus activity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## In-combat Focus Point Regeneration Techniques

(please add more as you come across them!)

### Classes

- Champion - [Desperate Prayer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1664)
- Cleric - [Surging Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1702)
- Wizard - [Linked Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=643)

### Ancestries

- Gnome - [Energized Font](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=33)

### Items

- [Cassock of Devotion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=420) (Cleric or Paladin)
- [Druid's Vestments](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=434) (Druid)

### Other

- Familiar - [Familiar Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=15) master ability